# Using spree mailer gem [SPREE 3.3]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Sending a test mail from the admin mail method settings interface shows this error
`Test Mail error: no implicit conversion of nil into Hash`
SMTP SETTING
SMTP DOMAIN :gmail.com
SMTP MAIL HOST: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP PORT: 465
Connection : SSL
auth type: login
username: my account email
password: my account password.

Different port and connection gets different error
`Test Mail error: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol`
SMTP SETTING
SMTP DOMAIN :gmail.com
SMTP MAIL HOST: smtp.gmail.com
SMTP PORT: 587
Connection : TLS
auth type: login
username: my account email
password: my account password.

> Spree.rb file
>
> ```
> Spree.config do |config|
>   # Example:
>   # Uncomment to stop tracking inventory levels in the application
>   # config.track_inventory_levels = false
>   config.logo = "jia.png"
>   config.currency = 'PHP'
>
>
> end
>
> Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
> ```
>
> my gem file
>
> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
>   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
>   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
> end
> gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'
> gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings'
> gem 'aws-sdk'
> gem 'spree', '~> 3.3.0'
> gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.3'
> gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.3'
> # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
> gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'
> # Usee postgresql as the database for Active Record
> gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
> # Use Puma as the app server
> gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
> # Use SCSS for stylesheets
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
> # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
> gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
> # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
> # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
>
> # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
> gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
> # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
> gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
> # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
> gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
> # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
> # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
> # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
> # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
>
> # Use Capistrano for deployment
> # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
>
> group :development, :test do
>   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
>   gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
>   # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
>   gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
>   gem 'selenium-webdriver'
> end
>
> group :development do
>   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
>   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
>   gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
>   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
>   gem 'spring'
>   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
> end
>
> # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to turn off google restriction on less secured apps for the second time, it keeps turning itself on.